# Locate asteroid in asteroid belt

Tags: orbit

I was interested in tracking the orbit of 1986 DA. I couldn't find any resource when I looked. Just for fun, so any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It has been observed 1977, and in 1994](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/mpec/J94/J94T11.html).
It should be near its perihelion this year (2014) around august 7 (using [wikipedia data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%286178%29_1986_DA), perihelion at March 6, 2005 and period 4.71 years), give or take a few days.

Answer (score 0):

The IAU's [Minor Planet Center](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/) is the authoritative place to go to for information on any asteroid.